# Jmicron ethernet not working ( tried everything )

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, ethernet

I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 with windows dualboot. Now, my ethernet is not working on Ubuntu but it's working on windows. I googled out and tried everything but nothing changed. Here are some outputs:

sudo lshw -class network

```
    *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 10
       serial: 48:5d:60:44:42:f4
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192se driverversion=4.15.0-46-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0500000-f0503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
       physical id: 0.5
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.5
       logical name: enp6s0f5
       version: 03
       serial: 00:90:f5:ae:76:c7
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msix msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=jme driverversion=1.0.8 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:f0600000-f0603fff ioport:4400(size=128) ioport:4000(size=256)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s29u1u1
       serial: 36:2f:77:15:b4:6b
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.35 link=yes multicast=yes
```

**sudo ethtool enp6s0f5**

```
Settings for enp6s0f5:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: pg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x000020c6 (8390)
               probe link rx_err tx_err hw
Link detected: no
```

**dmesg | grep -e jme -e enp6**

```
[    5.490070] jme: JMicron JMC2XX ethernet driver version 1.0.8
[    5.492985] jme 0000:06:00.5: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    5.493973] jme 0000:06:00.5 eth0: JMC250 Gigabit Ethernet chiprev:23 pcirev:3 macaddr:00:90:f5:ae:76:c7
[    5.550393] jme 0000:06:00.5 enp6s0f5: renamed from eth0
[   27.900666] jme 0000:06:00.5 enp6s0f5: Link is down
[   27.900725] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp6s0f5: link is not ready
[   31.555055] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp6s0f5: link is not ready
```

lsmod | grep jme

```
jme                    40960  0
mii                    16384  2 usbnet,jme
```

ifconfig -a

```
enp0s29u1u1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:2f:77:15:b4:6b  
          inet addr:192.168.42.35  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7834:7173:24c5:7b14/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7069 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3726480 (3.7 MB)  TX bytes:1225159 (1.2 MB)

enp6s0f5  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:f5:ae:76:c7  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:27 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:51893 (51.8 KB)  TX bytes:51893 (51.8 KB)

wlp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5d:60:44:42:f4  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Please Help..

Comment: I see no problems in the outputs except that you run ethtool on eth0 that doesn't exist.

Comment: With a known working ethernet cable connected to the jmicron, please run: `sudo ethtool enp6s0f5` and also: `dmesg | grep -e jme -e enp6` Next, edit your question to show the results. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the quick reply. I have done as asked and edited the question to show the results. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [know bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1497005) since a few years ago, with no definitive solution. JMicron responded the following:

> The JMC25x/JMC26x Gigabit Ethernet Chip was mass production at 2008Y, at that time, the IEEE802.3az specification wasn’t ready. So this chip will have a connection issue while connecting to all the IEEE 802.3az enabled devices, that is, if the ‘Speed & Duplex’ feature sets to ”Auto Negotiation” mode or ”1Gbps/Full Duplex” mode, then the link function is abnormal, i.e. link down. Therefore our S/W engineer made a workaround - ASD(Auto-Speed-Down) function to force the LAN speed keeping in 100Mbps when the ‘Speed & Duplex’ feature has been set to “Auto Negotiation” mode or ”1Gbps/Full Duplex” mode.
>    My suggestion is to use non-IEEE802.3az Gigabit equipment then your connection speed would keep as 1Gbps.

All you can do to make it work is to limit the link speed to 100 mbps:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full
```

But this is usually lost between reboots (I don't know how to properly make it permanent yet).

I have exactly the same problem. Everything was ok both in my Ubuntu and Windows partition, until I switched my router. Now only the Windows partition can work at 1000 mbps, but I don't fully understand how Microsoft is making it work.